# Playstation store having games PS5/PS4 and PS4

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus, ps5

What's the deal with Playstation Store having certain identical games tagged with PS4/PS5 and another version only for PS4. The example is Ride 4 currently in store. They even have the same exact price. Is there any reason for this, aren't PS5/PS4 games playable on both consoles so no matter which console you have you buy that version?